# paypal notify_url issue with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

i try to install paypal payment in my website, but i have an issue with notify_url

i have a form that sent users to paypal's website for the payment process, with this hidden field:

```
<input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://www.mysite.com/order/autoresponse" />
```

After the payment success, even if i put this code in the autoresponse page, nothing happens:

```
$this->load-library('email');
$this->email->clear();
$this->email->from('noreply@mysite.com', 'My name');
$this->email->to('my@email.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the paypal payment response.');  
$this->email->send();
```

Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you run this site (http://www.mysite.com/order/autoresponse) manually, do you receive an email?

Comment: nop, but when i delete the clear() line, it works...